# Авторизация пользователей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Есть сайт - интернет-магазин, написанный по технологии ASP.net MVC. Доступ к базе данных осуществляется через wcf-сервис.Для сайта нужно сделать авторизацию пользователей. ASP.net identity тесно связан с Entity Framework и требует прямого соединения с базой данных. Как мне сделать авторизацию и где хранить данные пользователей при условии, что база данных находится за wcf-сервисом? Проект чисто учебный.

Comment: Только создавать интерфейс взаимодействия для авторизации, по принципу работы ASP.NET WEB API. Самый лаконичный способ! P.S. Естественно в хранение данных в БД.

Comment: Данные пользователей - какие именно? Логин, пароль, мыло, ещё какая ерунда - точно в базе.

Comment: Да данные пользователей - логин и пароль. В базе той же, которая за wcf - сервисом? Но как тогда MVC - приложение будет будет взаимодействовать с этой базой. Какие Operation Contracts  и Data Contracts мне нужно будет определить. И куда собственно ASP Identity устанавливать? И в сервис и в приложение?

Comment: можно поподробней, что понимается под интерфейсом взаимодействия для авторизации?

Comment: я имею ввиду создать REST API сервис для взаимодействия сайта с WCF. [Посмотрите пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/218149/)

Comment: И к слову - в Identity 3.0 внесли изменения, и если не ошибаюсь - то там можно легко переопределить механизм работы с SQL-сервером. И ещё имеются вопросы, почему нет прямого доступа к SQL-серверу от сайта, поэтому можно действовать двумя путями: 1. Это создание интерфейса взаимодействия. 2. Настройка доступа к БД от сайта.

Comment: Доступа к БД нет, потому что так поставлена задача, что база должна быть за WCF - сервисом

Comment: Вы сами себе на вопрос ответили значит!

Comment: @SeriouSPK насколько я понял, суть вопроса - как заставить identity работать не напрямую с базой, а через ваш код, который вместо вызовов базы будет делать вызовы wcf-сервиса. Посмотрите ответ по ссылке на дубликат - там есть пример как именно подменить работу с базой на кастомный код.

Comment: @РоманГлебов суть вопроса в том, как отучить identity framework лезть напрямую в базу. т.е. именно в том, как именно "легко переопределить механизм работы с SQL-сервером".